# how to print strings on definite number of bits in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using VS 2010 - WPF - C#

I can't find out how to specify the number of bits that will be reserved for the string when its printed on the screen.

Back in Pascal we used to do `Writeline("some string here"):20` - and the string would be printed only on 20 bits.

How would I do this in C#?

Comment: It might just be me, but "on definite number of bits" isn't clear to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in WPF : `<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeString, StringFormat={0,20}}" />`

Answer (score 3):

This may be a close equivalent

```
string.Format("{0,20}","some string here")
```

EDIT:

For truncation, you could do

```
int length = 20;
string.Format("{0,"+length+"}", "some string here".Substring(0,length));
```

or if you don't like string concatenation `"{0,"+length+"}"` you can try

```
string.Format(string.Format("{{0,{0}}}", length), "some string here".Substring(0, length));
```

Comment: Pascal can truncate strings to fit.  But close enough.

Answer (score 1):

Not specific to writing to the screen, but you can get a substring of any string and use that for outputting:

```
string myString = "Something very long to be put here";

// Output just the first 10.
Console.WriteLine(myString.Substring(0,10));
```

Comment: You could also use LINQ and do myString.Take(10) or myString.Take(10).ToString(). ;-)